# Is there a limit to Elasticsearch Aggregation Names Length?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I'm reading through the Elasticsearch documentation and haven't been able to find an answer to this question.

Is there a limit on the maxmium length of a name that can be given to an aggregation step?

Just to be clear, when I say aggregation step name, I am referring to `my-agg-name` in the following example from the Elastic search docs:

```
GET /my-index-000001/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "my-agg-name": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "my-field"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I know this is a bit of a ridiculous question but I am working on a system that is programmatically building complex aggregations with part of its input coming from user entry - the use case is a bit complicated, so I need to know what limitations I need to impose on the user.

Comment: As far as I know the limit is 255 characters

Comment: Do you have any sort of source for this? Even the relevant source code would be okay.

Comment: Sorry I was wrong. I searched a lot and did not find any proof. I checked elasticsearch source code on github [link](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/cdcf238787f1be6cbc69f4cb49f8992ad26afff8/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/search/aggregations/AggregationBuilder.java). String is used for storing name. The maximum length of String in Java is 0 to 2147483647. So, we can have a String with the length of 2,147,483,647 characters, theoretically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried with 126500 characters as aggregation name. Inside this [example](https://gist.github.com/hkulekci/6e6a99a5eb46dbcdbe5d08249e9e218a),and I don’t know which user want to write such a long text in an input :). I could not see a limitation of the names in aggregation. As mentioned by @sinanorl there can be a limitation for Java string variable length. But I want to mention that the other problem here is request sizes. When you put there such a long name, the request size increases. This means that to process the request, machines start using more resources to handle this long-named request, and pretty sure that this makes slowness. So I think you need to force the user with a logical size.